# How to write MongoDb Aggregation for this Criteria query

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate

This is Criteria Query

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("careGiverId").is(careTakerId));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("careType").is(careType));         
        return mongoOperations.count(query,  CareLogBean.class);
```

How to apply Mongodb Aggregations on this...i will return count ....help me
 thanks in advance

Comment: i want return count in this scenario...

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with current query ? Why do you need aggregation ?

Comment: No problem... but while performance wise i want to use Aggregations. will it is possible to return count in aggregation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below for Mongo Server 3.4 version with Spring Mongo 1.10.1.Release. Uses `$count` aggregation operator.

```
 AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("careGiverId").is(careTakerId).and("careType").is(careType));
 AggregationOperation count = Aggregation.count().as("count");
 Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, count);
 mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, CareLogBean.class);
```